# How to make an SVG viewbox wide as its container?

Tags: javascript, css, svg, viewbox

I'm trying to figure out this, but having a lot of trouble:

```
    <div class="wrapper">
      <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewbox="0 0 100 100">
       <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />
      </svg>
    </div>
```

How can I make it so that the viewbox coordinates stretch 100% in height & width, following the viewport coordinates of the svg element?

P.S.
The wrapper  is 100% wide and has a set height.

Answer (score 3):

Just remove the 'height' and 'width' attributes from your SVG element.

```
 <div class="wrapper">
    <svg viewbox="0 0 100 100">
        <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />
    </svg>
 </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mhcp4qpy/

SVGs are a bit odd because they scale differently than most img elements. Most ppl 'overthink' it.

If you'd like the *height* to also fill the container 100% and never overflow, you can change the 'preserveAspectRatio' attribute on the SVG to make it so that it will distort beyond its original aspect ratio.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/preserveAspectRatio

Comment: But, I'm trying to get the SVG be "*responsive*". So, when I programmatically draw the shape using javascript, it's supposed to be responsive. Omitting the height="100%" and width="100%" is making my SVG item to be rigid, not fluid when I resize the browser.

Comment: What browser are you using? In the JSFiddle I created and linked, its responsive. You change the width of the div, the svg changes with it. You can drag-resize the jsfiddle windows to verify. I use svgs daily in my code and always make them responsive with this method. Or maybe I'm misunderstanding what you mean...

Comment: Perhaps you have some additional css set on either the svg element or the wrapper container that is changing the behavior? In my linked code, i just set the wrapper container to position: relative, 100% width, and a set height - exactly like you described in your question. And it works precisely how you want

Comment: You are absolutely right. I'm having a specific issue: I need to keep the "pixel perfect" behavior while clicking twice (via JS click handler) and render a SVG line on those exact coordinates, but also need it to "scale" down and have the SVG line element responsive on all browser sizes. I get the pixel perfect fit only if I use height="100%" and width="100%" on SVG element. Somehow I fail to see how can I have best of both worlds.

Comment: By 'pixel perfect'. do you mean keeping the original aspect ratio?

Comment: Yeah, and making the element (line) 'stay' inside the .wrapper div (relative to it and always visible on screen while resizing the browser). P.S. Thank you very much for helping me!